# Selenium IDE: entering ASCII values

Tags: selenium, ascii, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE, and every time I enter an ASCII value the recorder changes it by adding an extra . For example: `\9` changes to `\\9`.

Is there a way to correct this?
Or better yet, is there a better way to simulate tabbing, returns, and other non-character keystrokes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ${KEY_ENTER} and ${KEY_TAB}. For other keys it is the same as ${KEY_F8},${KEY_ESC}.. etc

Here is a blog post with more details.

http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/2013/09/25/using-special-keys-in-selenium-ide-part-2/

Comment: Is it possible to eliminate the extra \? For example, I'm trying to parse a " out of a string, but the additional \ is not allowing me to. I'm trying to use \" in this instance, but this gets corrected to \\".

Comment: This problem is giving me a hard time with regex. It keeps adding backslashes were I don't want them. Is there a way to turn this feature off?